# How do I back transform predicted values when multiple transformations are present in multiple regression?

Tags: multiple-regression, data-transformation, back-transformation

Suppose two predictors are desired for a multiple linear regression. Upon reviewing scatter plots, the first requires a power transformation, log(y)= b0 + b1log(x), and thus the back transformation of the predicted values are ŷ = 10^(b0 + b1log(x)). The second predictor requires an exponential model, log(y) = b0 + b1x, in which case back transformation is ŷ = 10^(b0 + b1x). How would I go about completing the back transformation of the predicted values to their original scale?